# How to uninstall multiple plugins at a time using npm-uninstall?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start, npm-request

I would like to uninstall set of plugins all at one time

Example:

```
npm uninstall plugin1,plugin2,...
```

It should uninstall all the plugins

Answer (score 1):

Please use space separated plugin names.

```
npm uninstall plugin1 plugin2 ...
```